# Enabling AuditLog EnityChanges for IdentityUser in ABP Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, audit-logging, abp

Enabling AuditLog EnityChanges for `IdentityUser` in ABP Framework.

Finally found this after hours of best practice search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `IdentityUser` to `EntityHistorySelectors` will enable audting.

```cs
     public class SampleDomainModule : AbpModule
        {
            public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
            {
                //Enable AuditLog EntityChanges for IdentityUser
                Configure<AbpAuditingOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.EntityHistorySelectors.Add(new NamedTypeSelector("AuditIdentityUser",type => typeof(IdentityUser).IsAssignableFrom(type)));
                });
    
                Configure<AbpMultiTenancyOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.IsEnabled = MultiTenancyConsts.IsEnabled;
                });
            }
        }
```